# Unable to send email from my php application hosted on a company's sub domain

Tags: php, email, cakephp

The basic scenario is like this :

I have cakePHP application which i sold to a client.

The client's main network is in the US and hence the sub domain(ticket.abc.com) where i need to host my application was created in the US, however they did not give me FTP access to their sub domain. Hence the sub domain was directed to an local IP address in the India office, this PC is a simple desktop with windows and i have installed WAMP on this to run my application through the local host.

The problem i am facing is that when i use a email ID of their company i.e xyz@abc.com to send an email notification i get an error saying  "Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?". I have read all the answers given in this forum but none of them solved my problem.

Hence we moved to using a gmail ID to send the email notifications, the thing worked for sometime and stopped all of sudden a few days back, when i researched i found that gmail has blacklisted that email ID to send mails.(Maybe because i am sending close to 100 mails a day, or because at some point of time an IP address was used to access the application instead of the URL)

Can someone please please help me?

Comment: To send emails from a different domain than the PHP host, I reccommend configuring PHP, or the app, to use the SMTP server of the domain you want to use for emails.  Your emails will get sent to spam folders if the sending IP does not match up with the domain.

Comment: you should consider a service like mailchimp or Amazon SES if you send large number of emails.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail stoped your mails by setting your email ID into blacklist.

Only Gmail (Google) can solve this situation.

Ask to google the reason why your email ID was blacklisted.